# Parse Oracle query to JSON format for using ANGULARJS + APEX(ORACLE)

Tags: angularjs, json, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I was wondering if it is possible to parse a ORACLE pl/sql query into a JSON format? 
The thing is that I want to use ANGULARJS directives with an oracle APEX app.
So, is it possible, or any suggestion? please.

Comment: I don't got your problem. Do you want the result of a SQL in JSON?

Comment: Yes, I do. But I got it, thank you.

Comment: You should really try building a REST service that returns JSON instead of hacking about with PL/SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the xmltype to convert the result of an SQL into XML and JSON. See the following article for the solution which will work for Oracle since version 9. You can also download the package itstar_xml_util:

[Oracle XML and JSON Goodies](http://stefan-armbruster.com/index.php/12-it/pl-sql/12-oracle-xml-and-json-goodies)

A simple example with the emp table:

```
declare
  l_sql_string varchar2(2000);
  l_xml        xmltype;
  l_json       xmltype;
begin
  l_sql_string := 'select a.empno, a.ename, a.job from emp a';

  -- Create the XML aus SQL
  l_xml := itstar_xml_util.sql2xml(l_sql_string);

  -- Display the XML
  dbms_output.put_line(l_xml.getclobval());

  l_json := itstar_xml_util.xml2json(l_xml);
  -- Display the JSON
  dbms_output.put_line(l_json.getclobval());  
end;
```

The result looks like this:

```
{"ROWSET": [
    {
      "EMPNO": 7839,
      "ENAME": "KING",
      "JOB": "PRESIDENT"
    },
    {
      "EMPNO": 7698,
      "ENAME": "BLAKE",
      "JOB": "MANAGER"
    },
[...]
    {
      "EMPNO": 7934,
      "ENAME": "MILLER",
      "JOB": "CLERK"
    }
  ]}
```

Answer (score 1):

With ORDS 3.0 (and earlier) you can easily use the "RESTful services" part of apex to quickly create JSON based rest services.

I am currently in a project where I am the single back-end developer and 6 angularjs programmers working with JSON I create using PLSQL/SQL/[ORDS 3.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/rest-data-services/overview/index.html)/[APEX 5.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/downloads/index.html)/[Glassfish 4.1 web edition](https://glassfish.java.net/download.html)  I also use the new API APEX_JSON for crunching json data in PLSQL.

They can not keep up with me. It's that simple creating fully functional back-end that is REST enabled.

Database is 11.2

Example of some simple lookup values REST definition. Accessed as JSON.

[image: Example of some simple lookup values for use in Angular. All accessible by REST]